# Need to URL Encode labels when tracking events with Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, urlencode, google-analytics-api, urldecode

when calling Google Analytics' trackEvent function, do I need to URL encode the label value?

_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'my category', 'my action', 'does this part need url encoding?']);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No but if you are wrapping your string in `''` then you need to escape any `'` contained in it with `\'`.

See this documentation page which shows samples of your question with spaces in that have not been url encoded:

- http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html